# Proxy that is NOT web based?

Tags: proxy

We have a problem with a service we connect to being dropped somewhere along the trace route.  I am looking for a proxy server that is NOT web based so that I can change the ip we're trying to access to something else.

I say NOT web based because I need to be able to put the ip address (alternative) into sql connection strings and other similar usages.

Does anyone know of a (preferably free, and/or preferably trustworthy) proxy server that will enable me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vidalia](https://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en) / Onion `TOR` to pass all traffic through proxy on your PC and get to public internet from random place on the planet (another TOR node). It will allow you to point any application to local port to route the traffic.
Any application that allows proxy configuration of course.

Comment: Our issue went away, but I will try Vidalia next time (if there is a next time)  Thankyou.